# Como mejorar tiempos de envío de PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

¿Cómo puedo mejorar el tiempo de envío? Actualmente mysqli esta demorando 0,1 segundos y PHP Mailer 8,1 Segundos, al parecer se trataría del uso de muchas variables en el cuerpo y cabecera del mensaje, ¿se podrá optimizar?

```
<?php
include_once 'class.phpmailer.php';

$vNombreSolicitante = $_POST['NombreSolicitante'];
$vCorreoElectronico = $_POST['CorreoElectronico'];
$vTelefono          = $_POST['Telefono'];
$vCodigoEmpresa     = $_POST['CodigoEmpresa'];
$vCentroCosto       = $_POST['CentroCosto'];
$vNombrePasajero    = $_POST['NombrePasajero'];
$vFecha             = $_POST['Fecha'];
$vFechaIn           = $_POST['Fecha'];
$vFechaOut          = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($vFechaIn));
$vHora              = $_POST['Hora'];
$vVuelo             = $_POST['Vuelo'];
$vDireccionOrigen   = $_POST['DireccionOrigen'];
$vDireccionDestino  = $_POST['DireccionDestino'];
$server             = "localhost";
$username           = "";
$password           = "";
$db                 = "";
$conn               = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO reservas (Estado, Nombre_Solicitante, Correo_Electronico, Telefono, Codigo_Empresa, Centro_Costo, Nombre_Pasajero, Fecha, FechaCL, Hora, Vuelo, Direccion_Origen, Direccion_Destino)
              VALUES ('Pendiente', '$vNombreSolicitante', '$vCorreoElectronico', '$vTelefono', '$vCodigoEmpresa', '$vCentroCosto', '$vNombrePasajero', '$vFecha', '$vFechaOut', '$vHora', '$vVuelo', '$vDireccionOrigen', '$vDireccionDestino' )";
if ($conn->query($query) === true) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

mysqli_commit($conn);
$conn->close();
$mail          = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->FromName = "$vNombreSolicitante";
$mail->From     = "$vCorreoElectronico";
$mail->Subject  = "Reserva: $last_id $vFechaOut $vHora $vCodigoEmpresa";
$mail->AddAddress("$vCorreoElectronico");
$mail->Body = "
    <strong>Numero de Reserva:</strong> $last_id<br>
    <strong>Nombre Solicitante:</strong> $vNombreSolicitante<br>
    <strong>Correo Electronico:</strong> $vCorreoElectronico<br>
    <strong>Telefono:</strong> $vTelefono<br>
    <strong>Codigo Empresa:</strong> $vCodigoEmpresa<br>
    <strong>Centro Costo:</strong> $vCentroCosto<br>
    <strong>Nombre Pasajero:</strong> $vNombrePasajero<br>
    <strong>Fecha Reserva:</strong> $vFechaOut<br>
    <strong>Hora Reserva:</strong> $vHora<br>
    <strong>Vuelo:</strong> $vVuelo<br>
    <strong>Origen:</strong> $vDireccionOrigen<br>
    <strong>Destino:</strong> $vDireccionDestino<br><br>
    <strong>Importante: Esta reserva debe ser confirmada por 0000000 de lo contrario debe comunicarse con la central al +0000000 o +00000000.</strong>
    ";
$mail->Send();

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Has intentado detectar que es lo que produce la demora? Puedes usar la función [MICROTIME](http://php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php) para saber la demora de las funciones especificas, si no sabes como usarlo puedes hacer otra pregunta aquí mismo. Este es un ejemplo en github sobre como usar esta funcion [LINK](https://github.com/odan/benchmark-php/blob/master/benchmark.php)

Comment: Puede demorar algunos segundos según la forma que se conecta al correo. Cuanto tiempo esperas que demore cada envío?. Intenta agregar `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` y ve que te arroja en el debug, Aparece las horas de cada paso del envio.

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; sirve si no estoy usando un SMTP externo?

Comment: Mira esto: http://www.alphadevx.com/a/372-Fixing-slow-performance-of-sending-mail-from-PHP-via-Sendmail